# How to automatically generate a page-name.module.ts?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

So in the newest version of Ionic when we use the generate page command

```
ionic g page page-name
```

Ionic creates the page's directory containing the **page-name.html**, **page-name.scss** and **page-name.ts**. It does NOT automatically create the file **page-name.module.ts** needed for lazy loading and deep links feature.

My question is: Is there any way or any plugin that automatically creates that file for each new page (or for all the existing ones)? Or do we really need to create that file manually for each and every page we create for our project?

Comment: There's not an official way to do that, but you can take a look at [this post](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading/) where a script is included in order to do so (I haven't tested the script yet).

Comment: With Ionic version 3.5.0, the ionic g page page-name does create the page-name.module.ts on my system.  What versions are you running?

Comment: @StevenScott Is correct - upgrade to the latest and a module.ts file will be generated with new pages.

Comment: I'm running the latest 3.5.0. No page-name.module.ts is being created. @Sam5487

Comment: @StevenScott I'm running the latest 3.5.0.

Comment: May be you need to update your Ionic CLI too

Answer (score -1):

As i experience in ionic cli 3.5 while creating a page, the page module was not getting generated. but on ionic cli 3.6 it was generating. need to check on ionic 3.7 which is released today.